# Interpolation of arrays a rectangular mesh in Python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, interpolation

I have a mesh defined by N_x and N_y discrete values of x and y. For each discrete pair of (x,y) I have a 1000 element long 1D array (call it Z(x,y)). For an arbitrary choice of (x,y) (within the bounds of the discrete values of x and y) I want to be able to determine Z(x,y).

If Z(x,y) was a simply a float I know I could use scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline, is there any way of doing this without looping over every element of Z(x,y)

Comment: I'm a little unclear here.  You have a mesh of (x,y). Clear. What exactly is Z(x,y)? Do you really mean that you have F(x,y,z)? Are the z elements also on a mesh, so that they are defined at the same z's for each (x,y)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, I don't need to interpolate on the z coordinate. It's perhaps best to think about it as a stack of images - the x,y coordinates are simply the spatial coordinates of the image and the z coordinate tells you which individual image. I'm not interested in interpolating between individual images but I do want to interpolate every image.

Comment: It seems to me that if each "image"is independent, than you have little choice but to use RectBivariateSpline on each image that you want to interpolate across (x,y) on. It would not be hard (except it is a loop) to make a list of spline objects, one for each layer, to use for interpolating into each layer. Or, if you don't need to do much interpolation, or not on every layer, you might just create spline objects as you go along.